# How to set the default language of the Spartacus storefront?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

The Spartacus storefront has english as default language, i couldn't find a way to change this within the i18n settings in my app.module.ts, is there another way to set another language as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure this in the `context` properties.  There are two possibilities:

- static, configured via javascript, see https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/static-context-configuration/
- automatic, configured via site setup in SAP Commerce, see https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/automatic-context-configuration/